# No password hashes loaded john the ripper

Tags: john-the-ripper

I'm trying to use john the ripper to vbulletin hashes. Example command here;

```
john -w: D:\Leak\1.2billion.txt -form:dynamic_1007 C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\m2711\m2711-2.hash
```

output:

```
Warning: invalid UTF-8 seen reading D:\Leak\1.2billion.txt
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: The error message says that there is a problem with 1.2billion.txt

Comment: I changed wordlist but this time output:
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)

Comment: That does not look like the correct syntax for specifying a wordlist. Have you confirmed that you are using the right command?

Comment: 1. Wordlist and hash file parameters needs ' or "
For example: john.exe --wordlist='C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\1.2billion.txt' 'C:\Users\fatih\Desktop\m2711\m2711-2.txt'